How to directly open "Display over other apps" settings for my app without showing the list of apps?
I'm trying to open the "Display over other apps" permission settings directly for my app using the following code:
val intent = Intent(
    Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
    Uri.parse("package:${packageName}")
)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)

However, this opens a list of all apps instead of directly showing the settings screen for my app.
I want to navigate directly to the "Display over other apps" permission settings specific to my app, bypassing the app list. Is there a way to achieve this on Android?
App list for display over other apps
App setting for display over other apps
The code snippet above.
Also tried using different intent actions like "android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" with no success.

"However, this opens a list of all apps instead of directly showing the settings screen for my app" -- which device(s) did you test? What you have there should work, but since the Settings app is customized by device manufacturers, there is no guarantee of the behavior.

@CommonsWare I checked Pixel Pixel 8.

This code checks if your app has overlay permission. If it doesn't it redirects the user to Settings>Apps>draw over apps page to let the user grant permission. There is no way you can programatically grant yourself permission from Android Marasmellow.
if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
    val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:${packageName}"))
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
}


To directly open the "Display over other apps" settings for your specific app without showing the list of all apps, you can use an Intent that targets your app's specific "Display over other apps" settings page.
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION)
intent.data = Uri.parse("package:" + packageName)
startActivity(intent) 
}

you can try this its work for me.
